# Blockchain wallet Outgoing Payments

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info

I want to Send bitcoin from my wallet to another bitcoin address.
I have been working on their API.

> http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&fee=$fee

This is what i tried to do.

But here the amount is bit confusing to me. My product price is  `0.03000000 BTC`.
So what will be the value of `$amount` ?

Official documentation says: `$amount Amount to send in satoshi.`

And what will be the value of `$fee` ?

Documentation: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Satoshi is the smallest fraction of a Bitcoin that can currently be sent: 0.00000001 BTC, that is, a hundredth of a millionth BTC. In the future, however, the protocol may be updated to allow further subdivisions, should they be needed.

Further examples of units

```
1 BTC = 1,000 mBTC (millibitcoin)
1 BTC = 1,000,000 μBTC (microbitcoin)
1 BTC = 100,000,000 Satoshis
1 mBTC = 100,000 Satoshis
1 μBTC (microbitcoin) = 100 Satoshis
```

So `$amount` will be `100000000*0.03 = 3000000`

and `$fee` will be Transaction fee value in satoshi (Must be greater than default fee) (Optional)